# Evaluate escape sequences in QR code generated by django-qr-code

Tags: django, qr-code

In my project (Django 3.0 python 3.6) I'm using [django-qr-code](https://github.com/dprog-philippe-docourt/django-qr-code) to generate a QR-code from internal data.

This QR-code will be scanned to fill a form in another application.

To do so "Tab Key" must be evaluated in the QR-Code.

According to [the Barcode Reference](https://www.tec-it.com/download/PDF/Barcode_Reference_EN.pdf), the escape sequence for Horizontal Tab is `\t`.

Now, here is the problem Lets say i want to generate a Qr-Code that populates two inputs firstname and lastname, i tried the following code :

```
{% qr_from_text "firstname_value \t lastname_value" size="m" image_format="png" error_correction="L" %}
```

The expected behavior is filling the first input and then the second one, but it only fills the first input with the sequence "firstname_value \t lastname_value", which means the the escape sequence `\t` is not interpreted correctly .

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I do not really understand the problem. Your response contains a tab as well, if you *print* athe *repr* string, it will show the escaped variant, but this porint also includes the quotes, so there *is* a  tab character, but in the *representation* (not the *content*), it uses`\t` for clarity.

Comment: Thank you for your comment . Can you please be more explicit because i only understand "I do not really understand the problem" . thank you again for your help